# Error message generated during the installation of github

Tags: github

"yo is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file".This is what the error message i have got while trying to install the GIT-hub.By looking into the previous answers i have changed the variable path value too Though my issue is unresolved.Is there any other possible solutions to overcome this??

Comment: yo is yeoman-generator. give npm install yo first.

Comment: Thanks subashini.I have installed that too.

Comment: can you pls try npm ls -g yo to see where it is installed?it might be a path problem.and also check if npm is added to path C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm and restart console

Comment: I have checked the path and restart console too..Still its not working..